# using connection method in another class or Jframe

Tags: java, swing, postgresql, oop

I use this Class to connect to a postgres database, how I can use this connection in a Jframe or in another class?

```
public class ConexionDB {
        private Connection conexion;

        public Connection conectar() {
            boolean estaConectado = false;
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/evaluacion";
            String password = "postgres";

            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                this.conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", password);
                estaConectado = true;
                System.out.println("Conectando a Base de Datos ...");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Problemas de Conexion");
                estaConectado = false;
            }
            return conexion;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection connection = new ConexionDB().conectar();
```

You can use create a `Connection` as above and use it..

Comment: Thanks for  the answer, I did what you have said, it trow me an error saying that the method didnt exist in the class ConexionDB, but it was there, netbeans recommend me to create a method in the ConexionDB, so I did, then erased the same method, and suddendly the line that you gave didnt show an error anymore....its that a bug?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: how i am supposed to copy paste a red line  under the codeline and a light bulb with a red dot on it!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method and create a new connection wherever you want
for example

```
class A{
     publlic static void main(String args[]){
         ConexionDB conexionDB = new ConexionDB();
         try(Connection conn = conexionDB.conectar()){
             // use the connectionr here
         } catch (SQLException e){
             //exception handling
         }
     }
}
```